# How to get back from inside function syncronized in node.js?

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, callback, synchronization

```
function squre(val) {
    main.add(val,function(result){
        console.log("squre = " + result); //returns 100 (2nd line of output)
        return result;
    });
}

console.log(squre(10));  // returns null (1st line of output)
```

I need 100 as output in both of the lines.

Comment: sorry its already squre function (i just edited in my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends on the nature of `main.add()`. But, by its use of a callback, it's most likely asynchronous. If that's the case, then `return` simply won't work well as "*asynchronous*" means that the code doesn't wait for `result` to be available.

> You should give a read through "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)." Though it uses Ajax as an example, it includes a very thorough explanation of asynchronous programming and available options of control flow.

You'll need to define `squre()` to accept a callback of its own and adjust the calling code to supply one:

```
function squre(val, callback) {
    main.add(val, function (result) {
        console.log("squre = " + result);
        callback(result);
    });
});

squre(10, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

---

Though, on the chance that `main.add()` is actually synchronous, you'll want to move the `return` statement. They can only apply to the `function` they're directly within, which would be the anonymous `function` rather than `spure()`.

```
function squre(val) {
    var answer;
    main.add(val, function (result) {
        console.log("squre = " + result);
        answer = result;
    });
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as you have the asynchronous function  `main.add()` that will be executed outside of the current tick of the event loop (see [this article](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/) for more information). The value of the `squre(10)` function call is `undefined`, since this function doesn't return anything synchronously. See this snippet of code:

```
function squre(val) {
    main.add(val,function(result){
        console.log("squre = " + result);
        return result;
    });

    return true; // Here is the value really returned by 'squre'
}

console.log(source(10)) // will output 'true'
```

and [The Art of Node](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) for more information on callbacks.

To get back data from an asynchronous function, you'll need to give it a callback:

```
function squre(val, callback) {
  main.add(val, function(res) {
    // do something
    callback(null, res) // send back data to the original callback, reporting no error
}

source(10, function (res) { // define the callback here
  console.log(res);
});
```